# Formik - name and ID are not being passed to Field

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

I have a component like below, and when I pass name prop or an ID, it is not being passed to a component and I can check two radio buttons at once. Also ,how can I update a predefined field in initial values with value of a checked radio button?

In React Devtools it looks ok
[image]

I get the following error

```
Warning: Formik called `handleChange`, but you forgot to pass an `id` or `name` attribute to your input:
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Heading, OptionCard } from "../..";
import data from "../../../../lang/pl.json";
import { Field } from "formik";

export const Step1 = ({
    errors,
    touched,
    values,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleSubmit
}) => {
    console.log(values, errors, touched);
    return (
        <>
            <div className="bottomSeparator mb-4">
                <Heading variant="h3">{data["global.offer-details"]}</Heading>
            </div>
            <Heading variant="h5" bsClasses="my-1" info>
                {data["global.category-offer"]}
            </Heading>
            <div className="row">
                <div role="group" className="col-12">
                    <div className="col-xs-6 col-lg-3">
                        <Field
                            type="radio"
                            component={OptionCard}
                            value={data["create.blade.text-1"]}
                            name={values.kategoria}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            id={data["create.blade.text-1"]}
                            name={data["create.blade.text-1"]}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-xs-6 col-lg-3">
                        <Field
                            type="radio"
                            component={OptionCard}
                            value={data["create.blade.text-2"]}
                            name={values.kategoria}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            id={data["create.blade.text-2"]}
                            name={data["create.blade.text-2"]}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row mb-3">
                    <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label>
                                {data["global.category-offer"]}{" "}
                                <span className="red">
                                    {data["global.required"]}
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <select
                                id="type"
                                name="type"
                                className="d-block"
                                required="yes"
                            >
                                <option value="course">
                                    {data["create.blade.text-1"]}
                                </option>
                                <option value="private_lesson">
                                    {data["create.blade.text-2"]}
                                </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

thanks

Comment: We cannot look into the issue without proper data. Can u plz create a stackblitz code and include it here.

Answer (score 1):

You have `values` formik variable.
You defined name as `name={values.kategoria}` (example). When page renders, you have `name={values.kategoria}` equals to `""`.

You have also doubled `name` props, make always according to your `data` variable as you import it, as you did here `name={data["create.blade.text-1"]}`

Also good thing to do:

You define `initialValues` and assign your `data` to your `initialValues`. After, you are using `{values}` variable inside render component, example [here](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik):